# Customizing drop down values with parent's model values in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have few models in Django:

```
from django.db import models

class First(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=100)
    first_value = models.IntegerField('Value')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name 

class Second(models.Model):
    first_ref = models.ForeignKey(First)
    second_name = models.CharField('Second Name', max_length=100)
    second_value = models.IntegerField('Second Value')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.second_name

class Third(models.Model):
    second_ref = models.ForeignKey(Second)
    third_name = models.CharField('Third Name', max_length=100)
    third_value = models.IntegerField('Third Value')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.third_name
```

Now, when I try to add a new record for `Third` model in my Django admin, my `<select>` box is populated with `second_name` values. How can I display a concatenated string of different values from both 'parent' tables, e.g. `first_name + first_value + second_name + second_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the `unicode` method of `second` Model:

```
class Second(models.Model):
    first_ref = models.ForeignKey(First)
    second_name = models.CharField('Second Name', max_length=100)
    second_value = models.IntegerField('Second Value')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (
            self.first_ref.first_name, self.first_ref.first_value,
            self.second_name, self.second_value)
```